# LM7915 Spice Model

Tags: voltage-regulator, simulation, spice

I have some LTSpice model for LM7915 that I found in regulators.lib

[image]

So, all nodes connected, and I'm getting the error saying:
`This circuit has floating nodes.`

...and that error appears only when I add this part.

And this is how it looks like:

```
    .SUBCKT LM7915  1    2    3            
DD4           4   5   D_6V3_0 
DD2           6   2   D_3V9_0 
DD1           7   2   D_4V7_0 
DD3           8   3   D_6V3_0 
C2            9  10  5P
C1            2   9  15P
QTU15         10   9   3   Q_PNP_0 1.000
R17          11  12  4.2K
QTU22          3  10  13   Q_NPN_0 3.000
R18           8   5  15.65K
R20          13  14  1K
R19           4  14  75
QTU31         12  11   4   Q_NPN_1 1.000
R16          15   1  160
R24          16   1  1.8K
C3           17   1  10P
QTU30         18  12  15   Q_NPN_1 1.000
QTU29         10  16   1   Q_NPN_1 1.000
R15          19   1  400
QTU28         10  20  19   Q_NPN_1 1.000
R14          21   1  200
QTU27         17  20  21   Q_NPN_1 1.000
R11          22  23  1K
R10          24  25  1K
QTU19         18  27  26   Q_NPN_1 1.000
R9            2  18  7.1K
QTU8          16  18   2   Q_PNP_0 1.000
QTU7          28  18   2   Q_PNP_0 1.000
QTU6          18  18   2   Q_PNP_0 1.000
QTU5          11  29   2   Q_PNP_0 1.000
QTU4          20  29   2   Q_PNP_0 1.000
QTU3           1  29   2   Q_PNP_0 1.000
QTU2           1  29   2   Q_PNP_0 1.000
R13          28   1  400
R12          30   1  400
QTU18         29  29  31   Q_NPN_1 1.000
QTU1          29  29   2   Q_PNP_0 1.000
R6           31  32  6.5K
R7           32  27  5.6K
R8           27  26  950
QTU10         33   6  26   Q_PNP_0 1.000
QTU17         34  35  33   Q_PNP_0 1.000
R5           36   1  2K
QTU24         34  34  36   Q_NPN_1 1.000
R1           37   6  6.3K
R2           37  38  670
R3           38  35  550
QTU9          38  35   6   Q_PNP_0 1.000
R4           39   1  2K
QTU23         35  34  39   Q_NPN_1 1.000
QTU16          1   7  35   Q_PNP_0 1.000
JT1           7   1   1  J_2N3458_N 
QTU14          3  17  23   Q_PNP_0 1.000
QTU13         17  17  23   Q_PNP_0 1.000
QTU12         17  17  25   Q_PNP_0 1.000
QTU11          9  17  25   Q_PNP_0 1.000
QTU32          3  13  14   Q_NPN_2 10.000
QTU26          9  20  28   Q_NPN_1 1.000
QTU25         20  20  30   Q_NPN_1 1.000
QTU21          2  40  22   Q_NPN_1 1.000
QTU20          2  37  24   Q_NPN_1 1.000
R21           2  40  4.29K
R22          40   3  10.63k
R23          14   1  500M

.MODEL J_2N3458_N NJF( VTO=-3.05 BETA=699.53U LAMBDA=6M RD=1 RS=1 
+      CGD=2.81P CGS=2.91P M=227.1M PB=500M IS=114.41F 
+      VTOTC=-2.5M BETATCE=-500M KF=0 AF=1 )
.MODEL D_6V3_0  D( IS=10F N=1.24 BV=6.3 IBV=1M CJ0 = 1P TT = 10p )
.MODEL D_3V9_0  D( IS=10F N=1.24 BV=3.9 IBV=1M CJ0 = 1P TT = 10p )
.MODEL D_4V7_0  D( IS=10F N=1.24 BV=4.7 IBV=1M CJ0 = 1P TT = 10p )
.MODEL Q_PNP_0  PNP( IS=10F NF=1.04 NR=1.04 BF=50 CJC=1P CJE=2P
+      TF=10P TR=1N VAF=45)
.MODEL Q_NPN_0  NPN( IS=10F NF=1.04 NR=1.04 BF=100 CJC=1P CJE=2P
+       TF=10P TR=1N VAF=90)
.MODEL Q_NPN_1  NPN( IS=10F NF=1.04 NR=1.04 BF=100 CJC=1P CJE=2P
+       TF=10P TR=1N VAF=90)
.MODEL Q_NPN_2  NPN( IS=10F NF=1.04 NR=1.04 BF=100 CJC=1P CJE=2P
+       TF=10P TR=1N VAF=90)
.ENDS LM7915
```

Any idea why?

Comment: Does it help to add load to ground on all ports?

Comment: Hm, it does. Can you help with that, why I need load on all ports? (maybe newbie question). It works even if I add load on pin 1 and 2, I'm getting expected value on pin 3.

Comment: Not sure why you are having this problem but note that you must have an output capacitor for stability on the 79xx series. They're not like the 78xx series parts.

Comment: Yeah I noticed that, and I added these capacitors, but I was just wondering why I need some load there.

Comment: Spice limitation.